# Flutter-Firestore:- Unable to upload image to firestore. its says reference object is not found

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage, flutter-getx

I am very new to Dart, and coding in general. I have produced this code after watching tutorials on YouTube. For the most part, I have been able to troubleshoot most of my problems on my own, here I feel I need some help. I have written code to upload photographs, but it is giving the following error. Please help me understand this.

> I/flutter ( 7512): [firebase_storage/object-not-found] No object exists at the desired reference.

My code is here:-

```
Future uploadImagetoFB() async {
        if (_image != null) {
         try{
           String fileName = Path.basename(_image.path);
           print('The uploaded file name is: ${fileName}');
           final Reference storageReference =
           FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('profileImages');
           _imageUrl = await storageReference.getDownloadURL();
           print('The Image Url: $_imageUrl');
         } catch (e){
           print(e);
         }
        }
      }
    
      Future PickedImage(ImageSource source) async {
        try {
          final image = await ImagePicker()
              .pickImage(source: source, maxWidth: 160, maxHeight: 160);
          if (image == null) return;
          setState(() {
            _image = File(image.path);
          });
          uploadImagetoFB();
        } on PlatformException catch (e) {
          print('failed to Upload ');
        }
      }
```

[image: My Storage Location]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To upload photos to Firebase, use the code below.**

This is the string where I set the image URL :

```
  String? url;
```

Code for image upload:

```
    uploadImage() async {
    final _firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
    final _imagePicker = ImagePicker();
    PickedFile image;

    //Check Permissions
    await Permission.photos.request();
    var permissionStatus = await Permission.photos.status;
    if (permissionStatus.isGranted) {
      //Select Image
      image = (await _imagePicker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery))!;
      var file = File(image.path);
      int uploadTimestamp = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
      if (image != (null)) {
        Reference ref =
            _firebaseStorage.ref().child('profileImages/$uploadTimestamp');
        UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(file);

        var imageUrl = await (await uploadTask).ref.getDownloadURL();
        setState(() {
          url = imageUrl.toString();
        });
      } else {
        print('No Image Path Received');
      }
    } else {
      print('Permission not granted. Try Again with permission access');
    }
  }
```

Result of Firebase :

Profile Images folder :

[image: Profile image folder]

Uploaded image :

[image: uploaded image]